# Show legend with custom colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a column with color codes but when I use them I dont see any legend.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

iris$col = rep(c('#b580d1', '#9bb240', '#6a70d7'), each = 50)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = iris$col)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

I would like to have the same legend, but with the different colors as in:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values= c('#b580d1', '#9bb240', '#6a70d7'))
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to keep the reference in the column

Comment: You can use `scale_color_manual(values=unique(iris$col))` but better have named vector